# populate embedded zoho form fields using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, embed, zoho

I am embedding zoho form in my html page and I would like to populate form fields with some data. I tried using JavaScript to access the form fields using their names, but it returns null unless I click on the field in the inspect mode. I have also attempted to wait for the form to fully load using the DOMContentLoaded event, but I'm still unable to access the fields.

```js
var emailField = document.querySelector('input[name="Email"]'); // null
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to achieve this using zoho forms field alias

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).